# Fatal errors running Camel examples

Tags: maven, apache-camel

I am trying to run some camel examples on my red hat VM. I've got Maven running properly (I think), yet I keep getting fatal errors running any Apache Camel examples.

The errors:

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
Downloading: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/camel/camel-parent/2.16.0/camel-parent-2.16.0.pom
[WARNING] Failed to write tracking file /home/.m2/repository/org/apache/camel/camel-parent/2.16.0/camel-parent-2.16.0.pom.lastUpdated
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /home/.m2/repository/org/apache/camel/camel-parent/2.16.0/camel-parent-2.16.0.pom.lastUpdated (Permission denied)
        at java.io.RandomAccessFile.open0(Native Method)
        at java.io.RandomAccessFile.open(RandomAccessFile.java:316)
        at java.io.RandomAccessFile.<init>(RandomAccessFile.java:243)
        at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.TrackingFileManager.update(TrackingFileManager.java:96)
        at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultUpdateCheckManager.write(DefaultUpdateCheckManager.java:617)
        at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultUpdateCheckManager.touchArtifact(DefaultUpdateCheckManager.java:553)
        at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.evaluateDownloads(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:645)
        at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.performDownloads(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:535)
        at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolve(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:421)
        at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolveArtifacts(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:246)
        at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolveArtifact(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:223)
        at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultRepositorySystem.resolveArtifact(DefaultRepositorySystem.java:294)
        at org.apache.maven.project.ProjectModelResolver.resolveModel(ProjectModelResolver.java:193)
        at org.apache.maven.project.ProjectModelResolver.resolveModel(ProjectModelResolver.java:246)
        at org.apache.maven.model.building.DefaultModelBuilder.readParentExternally(DefaultModelBuilder.java:978)
        at org.apache.maven.model.building.DefaultModelBuilder.readParent(DefaultModelBuilder.java:796)
        at org.apache.maven.model.building.DefaultModelBuilder.build(DefaultModelBuilder.java:325)
        at org.apache.maven.project.DefaultProjectBuilder.build(DefaultProjectBuilder.java:469)
        at org.apache.maven.project.DefaultProjectBuilder.build(DefaultProjectBuilder.java:438)
        at org.apache.maven.project.DefaultProjectBuilder.build(DefaultProjectBuilder.java:401)
        at org.apache.maven.graph.DefaultGraphBuilder.collectProjects(DefaultGraphBuilder.java:419)
        at org.apache.maven.graph.DefaultGraphBuilder.getProjectsForMavenReactor(DefaultGraphBuilder.java:410)
        at org.apache.maven.graph.DefaultGraphBuilder.build(DefaultGraphBuilder.java:83)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.buildGraph(DefaultMaven.java:491)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:219)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:193)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:106)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:862)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:286)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:197)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
[ERROR] [ERROR] Some problems were encountered while processing the POMs:
[FATAL] Non-resolvable parent POM for org.apache.camel:examples:[unknown-version]: Could not transfer artifact org.apache.camel:camel-parent:pom:2.16.0 from/to central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): /home/.m2/repository/org/apache/camel/camel-parent/2.16.0/camel-parent-2.16.0.pom.part.lock (Permission denied) and 'parent.relativePath' points at wrong local POM @ org.apache.camel:examples:[unknown-version], /opt/Camel/examples/pom.xml, line 21, column 11
 @
[ERROR] The build could not read 1 project -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR]   The project org.apache.camel:camel-example-sql:[unknown-version] (/opt/Camel/examples/camel-example-sql/pom.xml) has 1 error
[ERROR]     Non-resolvable parent POM for org.apache.camel:examples:[unknown-version]: Could not transfer artifact org.apache.camel:camel-parent:pom:2.16.0 from/to central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): /home/datasphere/.m2/repository/org/apache/camel/camel-parent/2.16.0/camel-parent-2.16.0.pom.part.lock (Permission denied) and 'parent.relativePath' points at wrong local POM @ org.apache.camel:examples:[unknown-version], /opt/Camel/examples/pom.xml, line 21, column 11 -> [Help 2]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/ProjectBuildingException
[ERROR] [Help 2] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/UnresolvableModelException
```

I updated the ~/.m2/settings.xml with the relevant proxies as well.

Any idea?

Comment: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /home/.m2/repository/org/apache/camel/camel-parent/2.16.0/camel-parent-2.16.0.pom.lastUpdated (Permission denied)
 Well, it seems to complain about permission denied..does it have read/write access?

Comment: So that was one of the issues, I changed the permissions, but I am still faced with a fatal error:

[FATAL] Non-resolvable parent POM for org.apache.camel:examples:[unknown-version]: Could not               transfer artifact org.apache.camel:camel-parent:pom:2.16.0 from/to central (https://repo.mave              n.apache.org/maven2): Permission denied and 'parent.relativePath' points at wrong local POM @               line 21, column 11
 @SoucianceEqdamRashti

Comment: Have you checked this error `'parent.relativePath' points at wrong local POM` in your `pom.xml`?